# Knockout binding 'with' an alias 'as'

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been using knockout and am familiar with the 'foreach' binding where i can use an alias 'as':

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: categories, as: 'category' }">
  <li>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: items, as: 'item' }">
      <li>
        <span data-bind="text: category.name"></span>:
        <span data-bind="text: item"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a similar thing for the 'with' binding? I have tried it with the following code but get an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "with: function (){return { data:$root.profileUser,as:'profile'} }"

```
<div data-bind="with: { data: $root.profileUser, as: 'profile' }">
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Preferred Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: profile.PreferredName" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Preferred Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I see in the documentation that `with` do not have the `as` option like `foreach`, anyway share the model or one similar to the one you are using to see the hierarchy to help us reach a solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've demonstrated, the `as` option with `foreach` creates a persistent alias that you can reference in child contexts. If this is all you need, there's a new binding coming in the next version of Knockout (3.5.0), called `let`.

You can you use it today by including the binding as a custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['let'] = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm, bindingContext) {
        // Make a modified binding context, with extra properties, and apply it to descendant elements
        var innerContext = bindingContext.extend(valueAccessor);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerContext, element);

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['let'] = true;
```

Usage:

```
<div data-bind="let: { profile: $root.profileUser }">
...
</div>
```

Comment: I love it when I find one of your answers and then go to add the code and find I already did so a year ago ;-)

Comment: Any chance of seeing 3.5 soon? If not maybe consider update the documentation for `foreach`. The current description says `This can be especially useful in scenarios where you have nested foreach blocks and you need to refer to an item declared at a higher level in the hierarchy.` which might be misinterpreted to meaning any property on a parent view model can be referenced (as if the purpose of `as` is to bypass the creation of a new data context).

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Thanks for the feedback. I'm working on [documentation changes](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/2326) now for 3.5. I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`with` does not iterate over the object like `foreach` does, so there is no `$data` item to alias. You just reference the members of the object as if they were top-level items.

```
<div data-bind="with: $root.profileUser">
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Preferred Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: PreferredName" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Preferred Name">
  </div>
</div>
```